# Using Drupal to do what Digg Does

Tags: parsing, drupal, url, import, digg

I'm trying to create a site where, like Digg, a user can submit a link and using ajax it attempts to pull the metadata from the page into a title and description field.  The user can change either of these fields then submit the content.

Ideally a module already exists.  I tried playing around with Feeds, but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place.

I probably have to create my own custom module.

Any suggestions?  Can I tap into the Feeds API just to parse the url then take the results and do all the mapping myself?  Assuming I want to create my own form and bring in my own ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do that with Feeds, but I think it might be overkill and could be difficult to configure.

You could do what you're looking for in a relatively small custom module using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to customize the submission form, [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/arg/6) to determine the URL being submitted, [drupal_http_request](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/6) to retrieve the page, then the Form API's [#default_value](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#default_value) setting to pre-populate the field(s).

The [Prepopulate module](https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) does a lot of what you're looking for. If it provides hooks (I'm not sure if it does) all you would need to do is add the drupal_http_request, to handle fetching the metadata.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I figured something that is a combo of existing and custom modules would be the answer.  Any clue on how I can parse the metadata using drupal_http_request

Comment: I've heard good things about the Querypath module for that kind of parsing: http://drupal.org/project/querypath p.s. - You might get more responses if you accept some of the answers you've received for your previous questions.

Comment: Seems like this is an easy solution too: get_meta_tags('http:/www.example.com');

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal it's called [Drigg](http://www.drigg-code.org/) ;). It is supposed to a nice Drupal module to get the functionality of Digg. It will be worth a try I suppose.